psql prompt for creating database doesn't work
in psql i'm trying to create a database, but nothing really happens seems like psql is expecting me to continue with the prompt.
postgres=# CREATE DATABASE testdb1;

;
;
\q
^CCancel request sent
ERROR:  canceling statement due to user request
postgres=#

As you see finishing the prompt with semicolon does nothing just puts me on a different line.
I've tried different prompts like creating a user, which works fine, so my guess is i'm just missing something and doing something stupid.
I'm using:

WSL Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Postgresql version 14
psql (PostgreSQL) 14.12 (Ubuntu 14.12-0ubuntu0.22.04.1)



This CREATE DATABASE testdb1; should work. 2) To your question add as text update the following: a) Postgres server version.  b) psql version. c) OS and version.


@AdrianKlarev i've edited the post


Just to be clear you are doing all this in WSL? 2) What if you do CREATE DATABASE testdb1\g?


@AdrianKlaver 1) yes, it's a fresh install 2) same exact problem.

Try these commands at psql prompt: \conninfo, \d, \l and help  and see what is happening.

The statement is probably blocked by a lock. If in doubt, restart the PostgreSQL server. If that doesn't help, rollback all prepared transactions.

All of these other psql prompts work juuust fine, CREATE DATABASE just doesn't, at all.
@LaurenzAlbe i have tried checking other processes running i've tried to shut them all down but they instantly re-create and i get the same problem

Start the CREATE DATABASE again, then run SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity in a concurrent session and add the result to the question.

@LaurenzAlbe i have tried reinstalling whole WSL and changing from version 1 to version 2. It's working now

Then best close the question.
